# How can I optimise my code with BufferedInputStream

Tags: java

Suppose I have an `InputStream` that contains text data, and I want to detect all words and their `numLine`. I reach for every word in file and their `num` line and put the result in a map. This is my code:

```
public class IndexerClassicRead {
    private static Map<String, Map<String, Set<Integer>>> mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder = new HashMap<>();
    public static  Map<String, Map<String, Set<Integer>>> getMap1() {
        return mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, Set<Integer>>> showAllWordInFolder(String FolderPath) throws IOException {
        ShowAllFiles showAllFiles = new ShowAllFiles();
        Set<String> fileInFolder;
        fileInFolder = showAllFiles.showfiles(FolderPath);

        for (String filePath : fileInFolder) {
            try {
                BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
                int currentChar;
                int numLine = 1;
                StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
                while ((currentChar = bis.read()) != -1 ) {
                    if ((char)currentChar == '\n'){
                        numLine++;
                    }

                   if(Character.isLetter((char)currentChar)){
                        word.append((char) currentChar);
                   }
                   if(!Character.isLetter((char)currentChar) || bis.available()==0 ){
                        if (word.length() > 0 ) {
                            mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder.computeIfAbsent(word.toString(), v -> new HashMap<>())
                                    .computeIfAbsent(filePath,  val -> new HashSet<>())
                                    .add(numLine);
                        }
                        word = new StringBuilder();
                   }
                }
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {
        System.out.println(new IndexerClassicRead().showAllWordInFolder("D:\\Files"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the type & initialisation of `mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder`.  We can guess, but we might guess wrong.  Missing the beginning of the `try`, too ... or is it a try-with-resources statement?   Much more context is needed.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes This is Code Review, not Stack Overflow. Asking for an MCVE will likely lead to people turning their code into example code, which is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @AJNeufeld the OP added the surrounding code- albeit in an answer, which has been merged into the original code. Hopefully this provides sufficient context.

Answer (score 2):

## String Builder inefficiency

### Non-words

The first inefficiency deals with repeated non-letter characters:

```
   if(!Character.isLetter((char)currentChar) || .... ){
        if (word.length() > 0 ) {
            mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder. ... .add(...);
        }
        word = new StringBuilder();
   }
```

If you encounter a non-letter, you check to see if you have a word accumulated in the `word` buffer, and if so, you add to `mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder`.  Then, unconditionally, you create a new `StringBuilder` object.

If you encounter a long string of non-letters, perhaps a table of numbers, only at the first non-letter could you have a word accumulated.  But at each non-letter of this long series of non-letters, you create a new `StringBuilder` when you haven't even used the last one.  You only need a clean `StringBuilder` after you've accumulated and processed a word:

```
   if(!Character.isLetter((char)currentChar) || .... ){
        if (word.length() > 0 ) {
            mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder. ... .add(...);
            word = new StringBuilder();
        }
   }
```

Small change, but huge improvement.

### setLength

The second biggest inefficiency is the repeated construction of `StringBuilder` objects.  A `StringBuilder` can be reused.

Instead of

```
        if (word.length() > 0 ) {
            mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder. ... .add(...);
            word = new StringBuilder();
        }
```

simply reset the `StringBuilder` object to "empty":

```
        if (word.length() > 0 ) {
            mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder. ... .add(...);
            word.setLength(0);
        }
```

Now the same buffer is being reused to accumulate words.  Bonus: If the buffer ever reallocates to a larger size for an extra long word, this reallocation will not need to be repeated for the next extra long word, since the [`capacity`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#capacity()) is retained.

For more efficiency, you could reuse the same `StringBuilder` for each file, instead of reallocating a new one every file.

## try-with-resources

If an `IOException` occurs, you are not closing the `bis` stream.  True, eventually the `bis` object will be garbage collected and the stream will be closed at that point, but that may take awhile and the operating system resources are held until that point.

Simply adding a `bis.close()` statement inside the `catch` clause is not enough, since that statement can itself raise an `IOException`.  It was hard to get the exception handling & closing of files correctly written, until Java 1.7's `try-with-resources` statement.

Instead of:

```
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            ...
            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

write:

```
        try (BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath))) {
            ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note that the `bis.close();` statement has gone away.  Written this way, the `try ( ) { ... }` statement is responsible for closing the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) resources; you no longer have to.

## Unused

```
public static  Map<String, Map<String, Set<Integer>>> getMap1() {
    return mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder;
}
```

Why does this function exist?  Is the word map expected to be queried several times, and the same word map returned?

The caller can modify this map.  Perhaps an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) should be returned.  Ideally, an unmodifiable map of unmodifiable maps of an unmodifiable sets, though that would take much more work.

## Usage

`showAllWordInFolder(...)` is a non-static method that updates and returns the map.  The map, however, is statically created.

If a different folder path is given, and the function is called again, the files in the new location are merged into the map.  If files are changed, and the function is called, the new file word/line information is merged into the sets along with the old and obsolete word/line information.

Maybe a new `Map` should be created and returned?  If each call returned a new object, then making the returned map unmodifiable wouldn't be as important.

## Line by Line

Instead of processing the stream character by character, perhaps processing it line by line would be simpler.

```
for(String path : fileInFolder) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(path))) {
        int line = 1
        for(String line : reader.lines()) {
            ...
            line++;
        }
    }
}
```

Words can be extracted from each line:

```
var regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alpha}]+"); // Split using non-letters
...
            String[] words = regex.split(line);
            for (String word : words) {
                ...
            }
...
```

Or using `.splitAsStream()` and collectors, for stream processing of results without constructing arrays of the words.